# "Voy de compras " vs "me voy de compras"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, reflexivos

In my French textbook for learning Spanish there is a phrase that goes like this:

> Si Manola gana el millón, se va de compras con su familia.

Then, when checking what "irse de compras" means, I couldn't find anything, I could only find "ir de compras" which means to go shopping.

Later when checking some phrases with "voy de compras" I found a mix of "me voy de compras" and "voy de compras."

It seems that in the unconjugated form "ir de compras" is more correct than "irse de compras" but in the conjugated forms I am not sure which is more correct.

So, my question is which form is the correct or the most frequently used? Is the reflexive pronoun necessary, if so what is its use?

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18553/12637) answer yours?

Comment: Yes, so if I understand correctly, "se va de compras" would mean she is going to shop if she wins the million but because she hasn't yet won the million and this is only a hypothetical scenario we use "se va de compras."

Comment: But actually I find that the "me voy de compras" form is nearly never used.

Comment: Quite the contrary, that form is very usual. For instance, you cannot remove *se* from the first example you provide, If the action is not yet started or is just starting now, you have to use the pronominal form.

Comment: Both forms are not always interchangeable. If you say "me voy de compras", you are, let's say, in your house doing nothing and then you decide to go shopping (you start doing the "go shopping" activity). If you say "voy de compras" you are already doing the activity.

Comment: Voting to reopen because "Si Manola gana el millón, se va de compras con su familia" doesn't sound right to me.  I think this question deserves an answer in its own right.

Comment: How to reopen? Could someone tell me if "Is Manola gana el millón, se va de compras con su familia" is correct or not?